# How to create radio buttons in Mapbox that toggle layers?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to create a map using Mapbox/Tilemill that can toggle between four layers. I am working off the code (and function) written by someone else (found here:https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/). It works well (I mean it works in that it can toggle between the layers I want to toggle), but I would like to customize the block button display.

I would like to use radio buttons instead of block buttons, and I would like to give it a header and brief description, like this: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/financial-times-goes-mapbox/

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Thank you!!